# Google Play Developer API | Retrieving Reviews

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, google-oauth, google-play-developer-api

GET

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/{your_package_name}/reviews?
access_token={your_auth_token}

While retrieving a set of reviews from google play store service, we can retrieve only the reviews that users have created or modified within the last week. But sometimes google is not returning the results which are published on play store. Why this behaviour is happening ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: probably caching

Comment: May this can help you, https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data.

Comment: If it is super recent it might be caching. But can you edit your question to describe precisely the problem? Are the reviews just not in the list? Or does an error occur?